# Is it possible to convert html to plain text without changing style?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, string, rich-text-editor

Is there any way to pass rich text editor value to the controller in the normal text without changing formatting/style?
I am using cleditor as text editor.
This is my textarea element and how I invoke it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = {
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    controls: "bold italic underline strikethrough subscript superscript | font size style | color highlight removeformat | bullets numbering | outdent indent | alignleft center alignright justify | undo redo | rule link image unlink | cut copy paste pastetext | print source"
  };
  var editor = $("#editor").cleditor(options)[0];
})
```

```html
<link href="~/CLEditor1_4_5/jquery.cleditor.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/CLEditor1_4_5/jquery.cleditor.js"></script>


<textarea rows="0" id="editor" cols="0" style="margin-left:0%" placeholder="Write message here"></textarea>
```

I want to send value of text area to controller. I'm doing that using val().
But when any styling is selected i.e bold or italic, it's passing HTML value like this.

```
 <span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; text-decoration-line: underline;">hello</span>
```

I want to pass it as plain text but without changing styles.I've gone through conversion codes but they are giving me plain text.
So is it possible to convert it to normal string without changing styles??
Please help me out

Comment: Plain text cannot have styles; can you clarify what you mean by "plain text styles"?

Comment: You could use [markdown](https://www.google.com/search?q=markdown), but other than that I cannot imagine what you mean

Comment: `I want to pass it as plain text but without changing styles.` If I understand you correctly, that's impossible. Plain text doesn't have styling by definition, so I guess you're looking for a conversion to markdown, or RTF or a similar styled text format?

Comment: OK ,I understood all of your points . But my requirement is to convert that plain text to base64 with stylings.And when I convert HTML to base64 ,it behaves like HTML only and I want it to behave as text with styles.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the `encodeURI()` and `decodeURI()` JavaScript functions, or `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` and `Httputlity.UrlDecode()` in Razor. These functions will encode all special characters in a format that is save to store in a database for example. Once you want to use the data you can simply decode the string using the functions mentioned above, and load the html on a different place (for example with `Html.Raw` in razor, or by setting the `innerHTML` property of an element using JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about tag stripping, it is relatively straight forward if you don't have to worry about things like  tags. If all you need to do is display the text without the tags you can accomplish that with a regular expression:

<[^>]*>

If you do have to worry about  tags and the like then you'll need something a bit more powerful then regular expressions because you need to track state, omething more like a Context Free Grammar (CFG). Althought you might be able to accomplish it with 'Left To Right' or non-greedy matching.

If you can use regular expressions there are many web pages out there with good info:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2003/05/13/6963.aspx
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=html+tag+stripping+&btnG=Search
If you need the more complex behaviour of a CFG I would suggest using a third party tool, unfortunately I don't know of a good one to recommend.

Comment: Please do not use regex to parse HTML when all browsers have built-in DOM parsers and other clients can easily get one